# How change option+key result in macOS Big Sur En-Us keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I wanna add another result for pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, now I'm seeing `ß` but I want to see `ş`. I don't want change my source input to other language.

I just want to add special characters to some keys and see them with pressing option (⌥) key.

**system**:

- macOS 11.3.1
- M1
- En-US keyboard
- En-US layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) (freeware).

> Ukelele is a Unicode Keyboard Layout Editor for the macOS.
>
> Ukelele aims to simplify keyboard layout editing by providing a graphical interface to .keylayout files, where the desired characters can simply be dragged onto keys as needed. (The Character Viewer or Character Palette, available in the Input menu if it has been enabled in System Preferences, and shown with Show Emoji & Symbols, is a great place to find the characters.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I installed it and add `ş` on the <kbd>s</kbd> button but still with holding ⌥+s I cannot get this `ş`.

Comment: You need to carefully read the instructions. It's not the easiest software to work with & there are some very specific steps you must take to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I didn't find instructions!, the website contains just **about**, **download**, **support** and **contact**. where is its instructions?

Comment: Help menu is always the first place to look on a Mac [I know for decades Windows users have never thought to look in there, but that's because on Windows there is never anything useful in it;)) On Mac, that's where the help is.

Comment: @AmerllicA Once you get the hang of it, changing a key like that should only take you a couple minutes.  If any problems, just post in the users group, they are very helpful in my experience.  https://groups.google.com/g/ukelele-users